# Laravel: translate string in @section

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

My blade template looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title', 'Houses')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
... etc
```

If I want to translate the title like this:

```
@section('title', {{ __('Houses') }})
```

I get this error:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')' (View:

How should I correctly translate string in @section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@section('title', __('Houses'))
```